# Is there a good way to calculate date ranges in T-SQL using set operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data in an `#account` table describing member accounts and I want to know the date ranges when a member had any account with my organization, as well as where the oldest open (or oldest remaining, at time of closure) account was opened. For example, Member 1 opened their initial account on 2024-01-01, and opened a second account at Branch 2 on 2024-01-05 which is still open, and then closed their initial account on 2024-01-30, they have been a member consecutively since 2024-01-01, and their oldest remaining account was opened at Branch 2. Member 2 opened an account on 2023-12-05 and closed it on 2024-01-05. They opened a second account on 2024-02-01 and closed it on 2024-02-08, along with an account that was overlapped by this account. The `#account` table, therefore, looks like this...

| ID | Branch | Open Date | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-30 |
| 1 | 2 | 2024-01-05 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-28 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-12-05 | 2024-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-08 |
| 2 | 2 | 2024-02-05 | 2024-02-08 |

...and I want to put it in a `#member` table that looks like this:

| ID | Branch | Open Date | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2024-01-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-12-05 | 2024-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-08 |

The code I've written below does the needful, but it uses a cursor. Is there a more parsimonious way to do this with set operations?

```
declare iterator cursor for 
    select ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate
    from #account 
    where #account.ID is not NULL
    order by ID
        , OpenDate
        , coalesce(CloseDate, '2078-12-31') desc

open iterator
fetch next from iterator into @currID, @currBranch, @currOpenDate, @currCloseDate
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    if coalesce(@ID, '') != coalesce(@currID, '')
    begin
        insert into #term values (@ID, @Branch, @OpenDate, @CloseDate);
        set @ID = @currID;
        set @Branch = @currBranch;
        set @OpenDate = @currOpenDate;
        set @CloseDate = @currCloseDate;
    end;
    else if @currOpenDate >= @CloseDate
    begin
        insert into #term values (@ID, @Branch, @OpenDate, @CloseDate);
        set @Branch = @currBranch;
        set @OpenDate = @currOpenDate;
        set @CloseDate = @currCloseDate;
    end;
    else if coalesce(@currCloseDate, '2078-12-31') > @CloseDate
    begin
        set @CloseDate = @currCloseDate;
        set @Branch = @currBranch;
    end;
    fetch next from iterator into @currID, @currBranch, @currOpenDate, @currCloseDate
end
insert into #term values (@ID, @Branch, @OpenDate, @CloseDate);

close iterator
deallocate iterator
```

Comment: This sounds like something you can do with a proper `row_number()` column in your select, and then filter out anything other than number 1s.

Comment: Can you give more examples, like what happens if there are more data ranges, or overlaps etc.

Comment: ID 2 above illustrates why `row_number()` and `min()` and `max()` don't work -- if there are non-overlapping terms, I want those listed separately.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, I can't work out the logic to get your results. Can you check your sample data and results and also explain how you arrive at each row in the result.

Comment: I think I've followed the problem statement, how good the solution remains to be seen. As I understand it, it's analogous to #account being slightly unclean SC2 data (where open and close are effective and expiration respectively) at the ID+Branch grain. And OP is trying to convert that to an SC2 result at the id grain. So, provided I'm correct in that interpretation, it's a matter of removing subsequent overlapping intervals by ID and plugging back in the appropriate closeDate.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I made a mistake on the expected result in row 3; Member 1 opened their initial account on 2024-01-01. They opened a second account at Branch 2 on 2024-01-05 which is still open, and then closed their initial account on 2024-01-30. Therefore, they have been a member consecutively since 2024-01-01, and their oldest remaining account was opened at Branch 2. Member 2 opened an account on 2023-12-05 and closed it on 2024-01-05. They opened a second account on 2024-02-01 and closed it on 2024-02-08, along with an account that was overlapped by this account.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77963046/edit)  your question and add the above info there and also correct any previous mistakes

Comment: Please provide 2 more example for member 3 and member 4  little complicated and their output

Comment: Not really a full answer (will post a recursion solution shortly) but my lazy optimization of any cursor I find in the wild is to add 4 options: **LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY** options. You'd be surprised what these few options do to really speed up a cursor. I've seen them run 90% or more faster and no logic change required! Microsoft doc on these options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

### Looping or like Required

Sometimes in SQL you just have to loop and I believe this is such as case. Think of scenarios like below where range 2 connects range 1 and 3, but you wouldn't know all 3 are connected unless you loop through each range

Normally in these scenarios, I prefer recursion over a cursor. If you're not familiar, recommend reading up recursion. It's syntax is a bit odd and of course has its challenges and risks, but I'd bet it's far faster than your cursor at scale.

```
Date Range 1: -----
Date Range 2:   -----
Date Range 3:       -----
Total Range : -----------
```

### Initial Optimizations

Without knowing your data, I cannot be sure, but would assume most users only have 1 or 2 accounts at a branch.
If you know they only have 1 account, you already know the range. If you have 2, you just need to do up to 1 join and decide to combine or show as two separate ranges.

Can calculate those in dedicated step first, then filter them out from your overlapping date range query. I don't have the data to test, but probably worth a shot

```
/*Pseudo code*/

/*1 range means no work needed*/
INSERT INTO #final_output
SELECT * FROM HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

/*If 2 ranges overlap, just take min/max*/
INSERT INTO #final_output
select MIN/MAX(Date) #account HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND OVERLAP EXISTS

/*2 ranges total, but don't overlap, insert both raw date ranges*/
INSERT INTO #final_output
select #account HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND NO OVERLAP EXISTS

/*Final overlapping query looping query*/
Insert into #final_output
SELECT FROM overlapping_ranges_finder
WHERE USER/BRANCH NOT EXISTS IN #final_output
```

### Setup Data

```
DROP TABLE IF Exists #account;

CREATE TABLE #account (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,UserID INT 
    ,BranchID INT
    ,OpenDate DATE NOT NULL
    ,CloseDate DATE NULL
    /*Recommend add to actual table a it allows better use of index as SQL Server by default puts NULLs first (probably could name the column something more intutitive)*/
    ,CloseDateFunctional  as IsNull(CloseDate,CONVERT(DATE,'9999-12-31',120)) 
);

/*Recommended Index*/
CREATE INDEX ix on #account(UserID,BranchID,OpenDate,CloseDateFunctional)

INSERT INTO #account
VALUES 
     (1,1,'2024-01-01','2024-01-30')
    ,(1,2,'2024-01-05',Null)
    ,(1,1,'2024-01-28',Null)
    ,(2,2,'2023-12-05','2024-01-05')
    ,(2,1,'2024-02-01','2024-02-08')
    ,(2,2,'2024-02-05','2024-02-08')

    /*Added some more test cases*/
    ,(3,1,'2024-01-01','2024-01-02')
    ,(3,1,'2024-01-02','2024-01-03')
    ,(3,1,'2024-01-03','2024-01-04')
    ,(3,1,'2024-01-04','2024-01-05')

    ,(4,1,'2024-01-01','2024-01-02')
    ,(4,1,'2024-01-02','2024-01-03')
    ,(4,1,'2024-01-04','2024-01-05')
    ,(4,1,'2024-01-05','2024-01-06')

    ,(4,2,'2024-02-01',null)
    ,(4,2,'2024-02-05','2024-01-06')
    ,(4,2,'2024-02-07','2024-01-08');
```

### Recursive Overlapping Range Finder##

```
;WITH cte_OrderAccount AS (
    SELECT 
    A.ID
    ,A.UserID
    ,A.BranchID
    ,A.OpenDate
    ,CloseDateFunctional
    /*Personally, I don't trust ID columns as someone might update a record so it's out of order. 
    Safer to use own ID, Previous index will make this pretty low cost to calculate*/
    ,row_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID,BranchID ORDER BY A.OpenDate,A.CloseDateFunctional) 
    FROM #account as A
    /*OPTIONAL OPTIMIZATION FILTER HERE: Put the filter if you pre-calculate where there's only 1 or 2 branches - WHERE UserID/BranchID NOT ALREADY CALCULATED by PREVIOUS QUERY*/
)
,cte_RangeMatch  as (
    /*Start with any ranges where you know it's the start of a series of overlapping ranges
    Do this by checking to ensure there's no overlapping ranges with the OpenDate.
    Executing this separately could probably be used to verify how many ranges you expect to find at the end
    */
    SELECT A.UserID,A.BranchID,A.OpenDate,A.CloseDateFunctional,A.row_id,1 as loop_counter 
    FROM cte_OrderAccount AS A
    WHERE not exists (
        SELECT *
        FROM cte_OrderAccount AS DTA
        WHERE A.UserID = DTA.UserID
        and A.BranchID = DTA.BranchID
        And A.row_id > DTA.row_id
        AND A.OpenDate BETWEEN DTA.OpenDate and DTA.CloseDateFunctional
    )
    UNION ALL
    /*Loop through and find the next end date*/
    SELECT A.UserID
        ,A.BranchID
        ,A.OpenDate
        ,CloseDate = CASE WHEN A.CloseDateFunctional > B.CloseDateFunctional THEN A.CloseDateFunctional ELSE B.CloseDateFunctional END
        ,B.row_id
        ,loop_counter + 1
    FROM cte_RangeMatch AS A
    CROSS APPLY (
        /*Find next row that matches*/
        SELECT *
        FROM cte_OrderAccount AS DTA
        WHERE A.UserID = DTA.UserID
        and A.BranchID = DTA.BranchID
        And A.row_id < DTA.row_id 
        AND DTA.OpenDate BETWEEN A.OpenDate and A.CloseDateFunctional
    ) as B
)
,cte_LastLoop AS (
    SELECT *
    ,loop_counter_row_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid,BranchID ORDER BY loop_counter DESC)
    FROM cte_RangeMatch
)
SELECT  UserId
    ,BranchID
    ,OpenDate
    ,CloseDate = NullIf(CloseDateFunctional,'9999-12-31')
    ,row_id
    ,loop_counter
FROM cte_LastLoop AS A
WHERE A.loop_counter_row_id  = 1 /*Only grab last loop's results*/
ORDER BY UserID,BranchID,loop_counter_row_id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); /*Default limit of "recursion loops" is 25, 0 removes the limit so will loop as much as needed*/
```

### Final Results:

[image: Final Results]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is riddled with bugs for edge cases and makes assumptions about the inclusiveness of the intervals. But maybe food for thought if nothing else. And the performance will probably be atrocious with the two range joins.

Caveat emptors out of the way. Done stuff like this before with unclean sc2 data, where there are overlapping effective intervals that need coerced down in to non-overlapping intervals.

Rationale - With a left anti join, remove all records for a member id which overlap with the effectiveness of a preceding interval. Then, to re-impute the close date, with an inline correlated subquery find the maximum closeDate which overlaps from the original data.

```
CREATE TABLE BranchData (
    ID INT,
    Branch INT,
    OpenDate DATE,
    CloseDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO BranchData (ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate) VALUES (1, 1, '2024-01-01', '2024-01-30');
INSERT INTO BranchData (ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate) VALUES (1, 2, '2024-01-05', NULL);
INSERT INTO BranchData (ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate) VALUES (1, 1, '2024-01-28', NULL);
INSERT INTO BranchData (ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate) VALUES (2, 2, '2023-12-05', '2024-01-05');
INSERT INTO BranchData (ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate) VALUES (2, 1, '2024-02-01', '2024-02-08');
INSERT INTO BranchData (ID, Branch, OpenDate, CloseDate) VALUES (2, 2, '2024-02-05', '2024-02-08');

with BranchData_cte as 
  (
    select id,
           Branch,
           OpenDate,
           coalesce(CloseDate, '9999-12-31') as CloseDate
      from BranchData
  )
select bd1.id,
       bd1.Branch,
       bd1.OpenDate,
       (
         select max(bd3.CloseDate) 
           from BranchData_cte bd3
          where bd1.id = bd3.id
            and bd1.OpenDate < bd3.CloseDate
            and bd1.CloseDate > bd3.OpenDate
       ) as CloseDate
  from BranchData_cte bd1
  left
  join BranchData_cte bd2
    on bd1.id = bd2.id
   and bd1.OpenDate >= bd2.OpenDate
   and bd1.OpenDate <= bd2.CloseDate
   and bd1.CloseDate >= bd2.openDate
   and not(bd1.OpenDate = bd2.OpenDate and bd2.CloseDate = bd1.CloseDate)
 where bd2.id is null;
```

| id | Branch | OpenDate | CloseDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-12-05 | 2024-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-08 |

Comment: Just curious... what are you using to format your code with or is that all you?

Comment: @JeffModen Thanks, take a bit of pride in the legibility of this formatting :). Notepad++ does most of the work, set to indent up to the first non-whitespace character of the previous line. Then just a bit of muscle memory for how many leading spaces each keyword needs to keep the vertical alignment.

Comment: The reason I ask is because that's a format I adopted a very long time ago.  I used to call it the "River format" because of the single character "whitespace river" between the keywords and the other stuff and, yeah... I have the exact same muscle memory for the right-hand justification and pretty much everything else I saw in your code.  I also tend to vertically align "=" and other operators and I use alias = expression instead of expression as alias for the same reasons.  Nice to see that there's more than one of us out there.

Comment: @JeffModen There are definite more of uss, my formatting is almost identical. I did not knew that notpad++ can do such formatting I will look into that

Comment: p.s.  I do this by setting SSMS to "convert tabs to spaces" with 4 space tabs and then, like @Error_2646 does, a little "muscle memory" goes a long way.  From what I understand, Redgate has such a format in their SQLPrompt product.  I don't use it because I work on many different machines for many companies and many of them don't have the RedGate product.  Muscle Memory rules! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for your question... It works for the given data. But to be sure, I would like to have more examples...

```
SELECT
        ID,
        MAX(Branch) AS Branch,
        MIN(OpenDate) AS OpenDate,
        NULL AS CloseDate
FROM #account
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #account WHERE CloseDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY ID

UNION ALL

SELECT 
        ID,
        Branch,
        MIN(OpenDate) AS OpenDate,
        MIN(CloseDate) AS CloseDate
FROM #account
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM #account WHERE CloseDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY ID,Branch;
```